# If hvac on recirculate should any exhaust smells be coming through vents?

Tags: smell

Civic vti 1999.

I have a small leak in my manifold and mechanic told me if you’re worried about smells just set in on recirculate.  I have done and I’m assuming this means no outside air should come through the hvac system regardless of whether your ac is on it the fan is on?  Am I correct about this?

My problem is whenever I put the fan on I can smell what I think are exhaust gases coming through the vent.  It gets stronger the more I higher revs I drive it on.  At low revs I can’t really smell it.

Am I right that recirc should not let anything to be drawn in, and if it’s exhaust gases I’m smelling how might these be getting through/what do I need to look at?

Comment: You need to look at getting the manifold fixed.

Comment: That's a dangerous situation!  You know you have an exhaust leak and running the AC on recirc is NOT a guarantee that no fumes, which contain CO (carbon monoxide - a DEADLY poisonous gas) will get into your passenger compartment.
Do  yourself a favor and get this fixed properly!

Comment: @jwh20 can you elaborate why/how co or other exhaust fumes maybe getting into the cabin even though it’s been set to recirculate.

Comment: The recirc damper may not be closing 100% but more likely it's getting in elsewhere.  Cars are NOT airtight.

Comment: Even worse than what @jwh20 says: cars are designed so that the "recirc" button does not wholly close the air intakes: some outside air is intentionally and deliberately allowed to enter the cabin. So: fix the exhaust leak,

Comment: I'm with David on this one.  There are many manufacturers who ensure that a vehicle can't be forced into pure recirculation mode, by design.  Pure recirc mode can be dangerous in cold weather conditions with rain / snow as that cause window fogging on the inside of the glass. Best to get the exhaust leak fixed, pronto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jwh20 is absolutely correct - get the manifold repaired as soon as possible. Until then, make sure you're getting plenty of fresh air from opening the windows. This is a life threatening scenario.

A way to commit suicide is to run a car in an enclosed garage. You're doing something similar by letting exhaust gases into the car cabin.

Comment: So you are saying that my particular car has been designed like this and there is no actual problem with leaks elsewhere??

Comment: I’m not questioning you guys seems there is a consensus heret. However I’m also wondering it seems a common situation where people may have an small exhaust leak and they close their window. So why aren’t people dropping like flies.  I myself have driven with windows closed though to be fair I do open them asa I get the smell. If it’s really serious then people should be educated on this properly.